# Is there a way to include a VM parameter inside a .jar?

Tags: java, parameters, garbage-collection, jar

I have a game implemented in Java that was having a problem when running too much code from scripts: depending on the script language, the game could have these "hiccups" where the game would freeze for a couple frames every now and then, making the game "jerky" at times.

After some research, I discovered that was happening when the Garbage Collector decided to run. After some more research and testing, I discovered that using the incremental garbage collector (by using the -Xincgc VM parameter) fixed the problem. Yes, I am aware it makes the GC run about 10% slower, but it is the cost I pay.

With that background information, now what I want to do is package the game in a .jar like I have been doing so far, but I know no way of making the application use the incremental GC without using -Xincgc, and I didn't want to create .bat/.sh files where before the user only had to double-click the .jar.

Is there any way to make the .jar run with the incremental GC without needing some kind of loader (.bat/.sh) or wrapper around it? Is there some way to include that parameter in the .jar?

Answer (score 5):

No, there's no way to do that. VM arguments can only be supplied as command-line parameters to JVM invocation: [Java Tool](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can definitely do this with [JNLP](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html), which can be configured to add a shortcut to the desktop and automatically keep jars up to date, among other things.

Answer (score 1):

From just a jar file, you can't do this. Adding [Java WebStart](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/javawebstart/index.jsp) can allow you to add java VM commands.  If you are not against wrapping the jar in an executable [Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) will wrap the jar in a executable as well.  It only makes a windows exe, but it can make it on linux or windows.  I haven't found a good alternative for linux.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of too many java apps outside of internal coorporate or dev stuff that people run via clicking a jar.  Even a shortcut can specify this.  Fancier options exist that let you create an exe, run as a service, or even wrap the whole thing in an installer... if we are talking windows, similar things exist for linux.

Answer (score 0):

Besides Java Web Start, you could consider wrapping with JSMooth.  It gives an EXE which in turn invokes the JVM - you can provide arguments there.

Answer (score 0):

One option - I always wondered - is to re-run the jar program with Runtime.exec() call when the parameters are inadequate? Never tried it but seems possible.